# How to make maven run 3rd party plugins automatically along with 1st party ones?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I'm trying to add a maven `pom.xml` file to my project which I developed with just a `Makefile`. This project includes a JNI extension. I am using Java 19 on macOS.

I found that `org.codehaus.mojo`'s `native-maven-plugin` doesn't work to generate JNI headers anymore since the removal of `javah` from the JDK in Java 10. So instead I decided to use `org.codehaus.mojo`'s `exec-maven-plugin` to run `javac -h`.

The plugin is configured as such:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
            <executable>javac</executable>
            <commandlineArgs>-h ${project.build.directory}/native/include -d ${project.build.directory}/classes ${basedir}/src/main/java/${fqn_slashes}.java</commandlineArgs>
            <useMavenLogger>true</useMavenLogger>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>generate-native-header</id>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I thought that adding: `<extensions>true</extensions>` or the contents of `<executions>` were the right way to have maven run the plugin when I run `mvn generate-sources` but it doesn't do so unless I explicitly run `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec generate-sources`.

So how do I get maven to run the plugin automatically? (Also is there a documentation site for using maven that isn't completely broken or devoid of any usable detail?)

Comment: Where do you place `plaugin` definition? In your case should be in `project/build/plugins`

Comment: I put it in `project/build/pluginManagement/plugins`

Comment: `pluginManagement` is used for configuration only - when you want to execute plugin in must by in `plugin` https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#plugin-management